# Cypress cy.visit() function times out and skips tests only when opening a VueJS webapp

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, cucumber, cypress

The Cypress cy.visit() function times out and aborts all the remaining tests when opening a VueJS Web Application. If I open the homepage of any other site that is not VueJS, it works just fine. Here is my very basic config:

**[package.json]**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^2.0.1" 
}
```

**[cypress.json]**

```
{ 
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 8000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 10000,
    "testFiles": "**/*.{feature,features}" 
}
```

**[\cypress\plugins\index.js]**

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

**[\cypress\integration\cucumber-tests\login.feature]**

```
Feature: Login
    As a user I desire to login
    Scenario: Login to a Website
        Given I open a website
```

**[\cypress\integration\cucumber-tests\login\loginSteps.js]**

```
import { Given, When, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'
import LoginPage from './loginPage'

Given('I open a website', () => {
    LoginPage.visit()
})
```

**[\cypress\integration\cucumber-tests\login\loginPage.js]**

```
//const URL = 'https://www.google.com' // Not a VueJS WebApp - Works Fine
//const URL = 'https://www.gitlab.com' // This is a VueJS WebApp - Times out and aborts rest of tests
const URL = 'https://www.nintendo.com' // This is a VueJS WebApp - Times out and aborts rest of tests
// List of VueJS WebApps: https://www.techuz.com/blog/top-9-websites-built-using-vue-js/

class LoginPage {
    static visit() {
        cy.wait(3000)
        cy.visit(URL)
    }
}

export default LoginPage
```

**[Screenshot - Passing on Google]**
[image]

**[Screenshot - Failing on Nintendo]**
[image]

**[Screenshot - Failing on Gitlab]**
[image]

**[Screenshot - Passing with a local VueJS instance]**
[image]

**[Troubleshooting]**

- I have tried to revert to previous cypress versions
- I have tried non VueJS websites that all work
- I have tried VueJS websites that all fail
- I have looked around Google to find something in relation to this specifically, and all I find is that Cypress has the ability to test VueJS, but no details of it failing.
- There are articles on Google that talk about this timeout, and it normally has to do with increasing the page load time in the cypress.json (this context is non Vue WebApps) and I forced mine to fail in this way by setting my timeout to 1000ms, which caused it to fail...so that article did not help me.

  Please let me know if additional info will help to figure this out.
  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks! =)

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried using just http rather than https.

Comment: @mvoase: I just tried switching over to http, and i'm getting the same issue - thank you for chiming in ;)

Comment: sounds a bit dirty does that, initially my thoughts were around the amount of XHR calls that Nintendo was doing and actually it timed out before loading.

Obviously these are common sites, have you tried just standing up a local basic VueJS template and checking you can reproduce?

Comment: @mvoase: I have actually increased the wait to 50,000 just to rule that out before lol, and that could be the issue. So I'm actually an automation engineer, and this is the first time i've attempted to automate VueJS. In light of that, i'm not sure how a developer would stand up a VusJS template =)

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/simple

You could stand it up using this project and then point your Cypress project to the local host

Comment: Okay I setup that VueJS instance and it passed! I put up a screenshot on the original post....so now we know its not VueJS itself, it is the amount of requests. Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Nice, so yeah you can use cy.route to wait for the xhr request you want to wait for.

Comment: sweet man! I'll doing some research on how to work with cy.route, and i'll come back and let ya know if it works =) Thank ya Sir! ;)

Comment: No problem at all!! If you need any help give me a shout. I can send over a few examples if you need it just let me know.

Comment: sure man I would be very grateful for a couple examples =) Thank you again! =)

Comment: Cool, i'll try send some over later.. i'm going to post an answer to your question about using the template if you can vote it as the answer?

Comment: sure man you got it, I will vote it as the answer. Thank ya again! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to install a local version of a VueJS template

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/simple

Point your cypress tests to that just to validate its not the actual websites you're trying to test against.

If this works then its quite possible the XHR calls in the background of the sites you're trying to visit.

In which case you will need to look into `cy.route` in order to handle them before you implement your next interaction.

Example of a custom cypress command we use to interact with XHR calls its quite basic but affective.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('apiCheck', (endpoint : string) => {
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', endpoint).as('apiCheck');
});
```